# Grab a section from a URL and append it a link using jQuery

Tags: jquery

This a tad beyond my capability but what I'm trying to achieve is take a section from a URL and append it to a href link.

```
 <a href="http://www.mysite.com.au/?SQ_DESIGN_NAME=print">Print this page</a>
```

This links to a 'Print Only Page' design in a CMS we're using

Sample of a section I'm trying to append to after the initial URL

```
 course_cd=802AA&version_number=5&
```

So I end up with

```
 <a href="http://www.mysite.com.au/somepage/course?course_cd=802AA&version_number=5&SQ_DESIGN_NAME=print">Print this page</a>
```

As you can see the section I want added goes in between the '?' and the SQ_DESIGN_NAME=print

I hope this makes sense
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally figured out my problem. Thanks to everyone who gave me their time

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

  var path = window.location.pathname;
  var query = window.location.search;
  $('a#print').attr('href', path + query + '&SQ_DESIGN_NAME=print');

});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var toAdd = 'course_cd=802AA&version_number=5&'
var aElm = $('a[href="http://www.mysite.com.au/?SQ_DESIGN_NAME=print"]')[0]; 
//an ID would do wonders

aElm.href = aElm.href.split('?')[0]+'somepage/course?'+toAdd+'SQ_DESIGN_NAME=print';
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5ntF7/2/)

And you're missing a quote in the href attribute.

Comment: thanks adenneo but the URL I provided is just an example. In a nutshell grab whatever the URL is and insert it after the ?  and before the SQ_DESIGN_NAME=print. My only guess is some regular expression and using 'split /'?

Comment: You don't really need a regex for this, just split up the url and insert whatever you'd like, but your example is two different URL's, and not only the querystring ? To get the current URL, just use window.location.href ...

Comment: adeneo that sounds great! Do you have time to show me or update the fiddle script for me?

Answer (score 1):

Add an id attribute to your anchor:

```
<a href="http://www.mysite.com.au/?SQ_DESIGN_NAME=print" id="print">Print this page</a>
```

Then the jQuery:

```
var section = 'scourse_cd=802AA&version_number=5&';
var p = $("#print"), ph = p.attr("href");
p.attr("href",ph.replace(/(SQ_DESIGN_NAME)/i,section+'$1'));​​
```

**Update:** to extract the *querystring* parameters:

```
var link = 'http://some.com/?param=value&param2=value2';
var section = link.split('?')[1];​​​​​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4eqxe/

Comment: Thanks Patric How can I return the section of url as a string because its never going to be the same. The URL I provided was just an example, of one of many

Answer (score 0):

Use this to set the new `href` to your link, you can also use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()` if you are using modern jQuery versions.

```
var v = 'course_cd=802AA&version_number=5&';
$('a').attr('href', $('a').attr('href').split('?')[0] + 'somepage/course?' + v);
```

Print your new `href` just to test:

```
console.log('modified link is: ' + $('a').attr('href'));​
```

Comment: Thanks Oscar This is the bit I'm trying convert to a variable course_cd=802AA&version_number=5& -  'somepage/course?' + 'someURL'

Comment: I put what you need in a variable just to clarify :-)

Comment: Ok, I hope this will make sense and I apologize if I wasn't clear. what if the URL is now course_cd=900BB&version_number=2&. The URL's are based on different courses which have unique ID's etc

Comment: You just replace variable "v" value with your new text. In this case var v = 'cd=900BB&version_number=2&'; and that's all.

Comment: Oscar there are hundreds of them, so if there is a way not to hard code the var = 'cd=900BB&version_number=2&' but to store this variable into a string?

Comment: You got something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/xMGLt/ ? or where did the extra part of the links come from? You can make some logic to create an array or something, but answer me first :-)